# Multiply a column with a row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame like this

```
Name        Oil     Cream      Sales
A           0        900        43
B          12         0         76
C           0         9         48
D           3         0         33
E          12        98         91
Cur Sales  0.1       0.9       998
```

Now when I want to make this into a data frame something like when the value is 0 then I has to multiply for oil column 43 * 0.1 on A row, for a cream column on 0 (76 * 0.9) on B row and for Oil column on C row on 0 (48 * 01). Something like that.

Expected Output

```
Name       Oil     Cream      Sales
A          4.3                 43
B                   68.4       76
C          4.8                 48
D                   29.7       33
E                              91
Cur Sales  0.1      0.9       998
```

For numbers that are greater than 0 I did

```
df[df > 0] = " "
```

Which makes them blank but how do I multiply column value with row on that particular 0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select all columns and indices without columns `Sales` and index `Cur Sales`, comapre by `1` and multiple by column and by row:

```
c = df.columns.drop(['Sales'])
i = df.index.drop(['Cur Sales'])
df.loc[i, c]  = df.loc[i, c].eq(0).mul(df['Sales'], axis=0).mul(df.loc['Cur Sales'])
print (df)
           Oil Cream  Sales
Name                       
A          4.3   0.0     43
B          0.0  68.4     76
C          4.8   0.0     48
D          0.0  29.7     33
E          0.0   0.0     91
Cur Sales  0.1   0.9    998
```

Comment: It working good but in some places where the value is 0 there, it is not getting converted. Do you know why? Like I have a huge data on that.

Comment: @newbie - is possible 0 in `Cur Sales` or `Sales` column? If check `df.loc[i, c].eq(0)` it create `True` also for problematic values?

Comment: Yeah I checked that, it says true where ever there are zeros but they aren't getting converted.

Comment: @newbie - maybe it is string `0`, try `df.loc[i, c].eq(0)` change to `df.loc[i, c].isin([0,'0'])`

Comment: Nope, still same.

Comment: @newbie - data are confidenatal?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241643/discussion-between-newbie-and-jezrael).